# How are these emails entering my mail queue, and why is Google reporting "Bad credentials"?

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, postfix

I am using a combination of Postfix, Dovecot and Roundcube for a web mail system. I have a Google Apps for Domains account so am using Google's SMTP server for outgoing mail.

I noticed a couple of days ago my postfix logs reported a couple of deferred emails. On checking `mailq` there were a couple of entries like this (not exactly this one because they've been removed):

> -Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient------- 2A66F820CF     2889 Tue Jul 10 09:42:46  MAILER-DAEMON (SASL
>   authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com[66.102.1.109] said:
>   535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at?535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials
>   w135-v6sm3873050wme.7 - gsmtp)
>                                            donotreply@e.myyodel.co.uk

Yodel is a courier company in the UK and I had a couple of emails from them recently about a package being delivered. However, I did not reply to those emails, and there was no request for a read receipt or anything, so I wasn't sure where these emails in the queue had come from. I also don't know why they were being queued with the "bad credentials" error because I have no problem sending emails normally.

I deleted the two entries and I thought nothing else of it, until this morning when I noticed the entry above appeared again. As I haven't had any emails from Yodel since so this has got me more suspicious.

What could be creating these emails? I don't think it's malware as the fact I have genuinely received emails from Yodel recently make this unlikely.

Comment: could Yodel be attempting to send emails via your server and failing?

Comment: @SirAdelaide it’s possible I suppose, but I read the mailq entry as email being sent *to* yodel.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to forward messages to/via google without changing envelope sender email address
(as passed in `MAIL FROM:` in SMTP session).

It makes your server send bounces (reports about delivery problem) to/via google to unchanged original envelope sender.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. There shouldn't be any delivery problems creating a bounce as I didn't reply to the emails I received (and obviously the ones I received arrived OK).

Comment: Most likely It may be caused by email alias in you MTA/postfix configuration or some user's `~/.forward` file.

Comment: No, there are no .forward files in use or aliases that would explain this.